# How to prove $dim(Ker (A- \lambda I))=dim (Ker(A^t- \lambda I))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How to prove $dim(Ker (A- \lambda I))=dim (Ker(A^t- \lambda I))$ ?

We know both $A$ and $A^t$ have same eigenvalues and $Av= \lambda v$ imply $v^tA^t= \lambda v^t$ but this does not imply that there is a one to one association b/w eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^t$.. So how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rank$(B^t) =rank(B)$ for any $B$ thus $rank(A-cI)=rank(A^t-cI)$,
since $dim ker(A-cI)+rank(A-cI)=n=dim(ker(A^t-cI)+rank(A^t-cI)$, the result follows

Comment: Yeah thanks. It was easy but I couldn't see this early :( .  (y)