# The working of $\dim(\ker(X))$ in a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does a square matrix $X \in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ *always* follow that $\dim(\ker(X)) = \dim(\ker(X^T))$?
I know it works for a sizable amount, but I am not sure if it works for all of them, is there a way to prove this either way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $dim(Ker (A- \lambda I))=dim (Ker(A^t- \lambda I))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495940/how-to-prove-dimker-a-lambda-i-dim-kerat-lambda-i)

Comment: What do you know about rank / nullity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and there are many ways to prove it. The easiest is probably considering that $$\dim\ker(X)=n-\operatorname{rank}(X),$$
so we just have to prove that $\operatorname{rank}(X)=\operatorname{rank}(X^T)$; but that follows immediately from the fact that the rank of a matrix $X$ is the maximal number of linearly independent rows (or columns) of $X$, since $X$ and $X^T$ have the same rows (and columns), only "switched".

Comment: It's not entirely obvious that the column rank of a matrix is always equal to its row rank. It's so ingrained it's basically second nature to anyone who is experienced in linear algebra. It's easy to forget that it isn't trivial. Especially to a beginner.

Comment: That's a question that should come way before computing kernels dimensions though. If OP still needs to see that proven, I'm not sure if there's a point in giving a short answer to this particular question

Comment: (Also, clearly here I'm taking for granted the Rank-Nullity theorem as well)

Comment: I don't disagree there. But "should" is not always enough. Many (most?) students are pushed to the next section before they've internalised the previous. Just thought I'd point it out for safety's sake. I might have phrased it more as a critique than a complement. Sorry about that.

Comment: No no, you're right of course! It's never a sin to point stuff out